# If the same item is purchased multiple times in the same order, treat as multiple individual items

Tags: php, magento

I am pulling out order details in Magento (4.1.1) with the below code, which works fine. But, where a product has been ordered twice, I need to have a repeated row, SO If the same item is purchased multiple times in the same order, they need to be treated as multiple individual items - presently Magento returns one single product line, with a Quantity value for multiple purchases of the same item:

```
$_customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
    $lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
    $order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order'); 
    $order->load($lastOrderId);
    $_totalData =$order->getData(); 
    $_order   = $this->getOrder();
    $allitems = $order->getAllItems();
    $index    = 1;

    $data   = ""

    foreach($allitems as $item)
    {
      $cjData.="|".$item->getPrice()."::".$item->getName()."::".$item->getQtyToShip();
      $index++;
    }

    echo $cjData
```

If the same item is purchased multiple times in the same order, I need to treat them as multiple individual items - any help on achieving this much appreciated.

Comment: Don't know much about Magento but from a real-life point of view, if I order the same item multiple times on one order, I ordered one item with a quantity of >1. In order to achieve the effect you descibe, I would need to place multiple distinct orders.

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why having multiple line items on an order is an acceptable behavior. For instance we have items that can be personalized, and if you wanted to order the same item and have it personalized two different ways, listing the item on two order lines is a much simpler practice than trying to have multiple different personalizations attached to a single line item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try adding a [for loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) to loop for x number of times based on the qty for each line item:

```
foreach($allitems as $item)
{   
    for($i = 1; $i <= $item->getQtyToShip(); $i++) {
        $cjData.="|".$item->getPrice()."::".$item->getName()."::1";
        $index++;   
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this, so it may need some adjustment, but the basic concept is to loop until `$i` equals the `$item->getQtyToShip()` and on each iteration of the loop `$i` will be incremented via `$i++`.

I also changed the string assignment to `$cjData` to only have a quantity of `1` for each item added to `$cjData`. I think this should give you the desired result for what you are asking.